# How to compress a string

Tags: string, algorithm, compression

I had this question in one of my interviews:

> Given a string how would you compress it?

Example input is not in the form of `aabbccdd` but like `abcdgehrk`. i.e. all `chars` in the `string` are different.(Note:Run Length Encoding wont work ,as it was one of the solutions which I gave but he said string does not have any repetitive characters)

I gave the following two solutions but he did not accept them:

1) HashCode cannot be a solution as it will store numbers
2) Can't store in binary as its not human readable format

Can anyone please suggest what could be another solution for this problem?

Comment: There is one famous compression technique, which is [Huffman coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding). And what do you mean storing in binary? In memory, everything is stored in binary form.

Comment: Now there was a catch he wanted it to be in a human readable format .So huffman encoding wont work .Hashing was also one of the answer which I gave .Seems to me that the interviewer himself was not sure what he's asking or is not aware of compression

Answer (score 4):

Given that the examiner required that the compressed string is human-readable, one solution is [Run-Length Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding).

aabbccdd would therefore be compressed as 2a2b2c2d, and abcdgehrk as 1a1b1c1d1g1e1h1r1k.

Note that the output string in these special examples are not shorter than the original string, but it's a property of all lossless compression algorithms that they cannot guarantee compression for any input dataset.

Comment: Yes I had asked the examiner the same question ,aabbccdd is a easy task but its like how would you compress a string abcd .I gave the same run length encoding solution but he said no

Comment: Strings like abcdgehrk or abcd are incompressible given the requirements -- they're composed of all different symbols.

Comment: yes exactly thats what I thought.But since it was a big company,i thought that the interviewer wont be that silly ,but after getting through google i find it was indeed silly .

Answer (score 1):

If the requirements allow that a string is composed of only lower case alphabetical characters, then each character can fit in 5 bits (2^5 = 32 possible characters). An 8-character string can then be fit into 40 bits = 5 bytes.

Here is an example, fitting 3 characters into 2 bytes:

```
a = 00001
b = 00010
c = 00011
```

The string "cab" can fit in:

```
  c     a     b   (extra bit)
00011 00001 00010 0

00011000 01000100
```

In big-endian form:

```
0x1844
```

The requirement that it be human readable is silly. For anything of this nature, software and standards (e.g. ASCII) are required in order for it to be read by a human. With the right software and output device, anything can be human readable.

Answer (score 0):

I had solved like this question before, I will comprise string e.g (aaabb) after this process it will become (a3b1) then I will check if the length of the comprise string is less than the original string i will return comprise string otherwise return original
(ab) - > (a1b1) in this situation I will return an original string.
(aaaaabb) ->(a5b2) in this situation I will return comprise string. 
here is my code for this process it will take O(N)

```
   public static String stringCompression(String str){

    StringBuilder compressed  = new StringBuilder();
    int count = 1;
    int i = 0;
    for ( i = 0; i <str.length()-1 ; i++) {
        if(str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(i+1)){
       //     System.out.println("str.charAt(i) = " + str.charAt(i));
            count++;
        }
        else {
            compressed.append(str.charAt(i)).append(count);
            count =1;
        }
    }

    if(i == str.length()-1)
        compressed.append(str.charAt(i)).append(count);

    return compressed.length() < str.length() ? new String(compressed): str;
}
```

and u may use this algo to decompse data

```
public static String stringDeCompression(String str){
   StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
   int temp = 0;
   int k = 0;
   for (int i = 1; i <str.length() ; i+=2) {
        temp = Character.getNumericValue(str.charAt(i));
       for (int j = 0 ; j < temp ; j++) {
           stringBuilder.append(str.charAt(k));
       }
       k+=2;
    }
   return new String(stringBuilder);
}
```

Comment: How will you handle an input of (a1b1)? How do you decompress? *Never, ever* invest time in data compression while there is no decompression.

Comment: I did it, if u want to decompose data, u may use this algo                                      
 public static String stringDeCompression(String str){
       StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
       int temp = 0;
       int k = 0;
       for (int i = 1; i <str.length() ; i+=2) {
            temp = Character.getNumericValue(str.charAt(i));
           for (int j = 0 ; j < temp ; j++) {
               stringBuilder.append(str.charAt(k));
           }
           k+=2;
        }
       return new String(stringBuilder);
    }

Comment: So, what compressed string will be de*compressed* (not *decomposed*) into "a1b1"?

Comment: // stringCompression("a1b1") ==>  (a1b1)  // stringDeCompression("a1b1") ==> (ab)  yea there are some errors it should return the same string compression yea,  how we can solve it ??

Comment: The usual trade-off in [lossless data compression](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_compression) is to *in*crease the average length of all *possible* strings and hope to *decrease* that of the average string actually occurring: You got to successfully *model* the data to be compressed.